# How can I pass a parameter to a GET web request without it being visible in the URL?

Tags: html, jquery, jsp, web

I am building a web application Java Spring MVC, JSPs, and jQuery.

I have a URL like this:

```
http://myserver/myapp/showuser/55
```

Which shows the "view user" page (for user id '55').

I also have an "edit user" page and after successful edit, I redirect to the "view user" page by going here:

```
http://myserver/myapp/showuser/55?successMsg=Successfully edited User.
```

The "success message" is parsed from the URL parameters and displayed on the screen.

It works well, but ...

QUESTION: How can I pass the "successMsg" value to the GET without making it part of the URL itself?

Comment: Either don't use GET, or use a server side session to display the message on the next page instead of putting the content in the URL

Answer (score 2):

You can use btoa() and atob() to convert to and from base64 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

For Plain JavaScript Web solution:

You can use History `pushState` method to do that.

History's `state` is similar to params but it is hidden from the URL.

To do that, simply:

```
const state = { successMsg: 'Successfully edited User'};
const title = '';
const url = 'myserver/myapp/showuser/';

history.pushState(state, title, url);
```

In your Show User page, access the state like

```
console.log(history.state) // { successMsg: 'Successfully edited User'}
```